# How to get the latest value of a field from the table in Db2

Tags: database, db2, iseries-navigator

I am using iseries for DB2.I want to get the latest value for a column in Db2.?
I tried using IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() but this needs an insert statement.In my case I don't perform any insertion. I want latest value inserted in a column in Db2, which is necessarily not recently inserted.

Comment: Is the column defined as IDENTITY?

Comment: NO. not an identity column

Comment: Then why are you using `IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL()`? How do you identify the latest value anyway? By the row timestamp? I think you should publish the table definition and some sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a timestamp field on your table? You could do something like:

```
SELECT id
FROM schema.table
ORDER BY tstamp DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

If you don't, I'm not sure how you plan on defining "latest" (since you said in the other answer's comments that this is an alpha-numeric field that isn't necessarily in "order").

Comment: You may also want an index by tstamp, to help this query perform better.

Comment: What is the reason you want the most recent value?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT MAX(MYCOL) FROM MYTABLE
```

Comment: But this also fails. the problem is that column for which I am trying to get latest values is **alphanumeric**

Comment: I am not getting error message but the max value is not working for alphanumeric strings..